# Unable to deserialize JSON array

Tags: c#, linq, json.net

Below is my class :

```
public class Employee : Base
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Fname { get; set; } 
    public DepartmentModel Department { get; set; }
}

public class DepartmentModel : Base
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string DepartmentName { get; set; }
    public List<Location> Locations { get; set; }
}

public class Locations
{
    public string Area { get; set; }
    public string StreetNo { get; set; }
    public string Nearby { get; set; }
}
```

Response return from service:

```
var response = new
{
    id = 100,
    department = new
    {
        id = 200,
        departmentName = "Abc",
        locations = new[]
        {
            Employee.Department.Locations
                    .Select
                    (
                        lo => new
                        {
                             area = lo.Area,
                             streetNo = lo.streetNo,
                             nearby = lo.Nearby
                        }
                    ).ToList()
        }
    }
};

return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response);
```

Now when I try to deserialize this above JSON into my class Employee like below:

```
var deserialize = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Employee>(response.ToString());
```

Error:

[image]

How can I deserialize this above JSON?

Comment: Please show the *actual JSON returned* rather than how you returned it. Ideally, provide this as a [mcve].

Comment: You just need to remove new[] for location key because LINQ expression ends with .ToList() already returns a list of items.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem lies here:

```
locations = new[]
            {
                Employee.Department.Locations
                        .Select
                        (
                            lo => new
                            {
                                area = lo.Area,
                                streetNo = lo.streetNo,
                                nearby = lo.Nearby
                            }
                        ).ToList()
            }
```

The LINQ expression  ends with `.ToList()` and thus is already returning a list of items. You are then wrapping that with `new[]` in an array. So, instead of being an array of `Location`s, the JSON is an array of *an array of* `Location`s.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer and yes you are right.Once again thank you so much and please keep helping like this :)

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the `new[]`. You don't want locations to be an array of lists

```
locations = Employee.Department.Locations
                               .Select(lo => new
                                           {
                                                 area = lo.Area,
                                                 streetNo = lo.streetNo,
                                                 nearby = lo.Nearby
                                            }
                                        ).ToList()
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to instantiate a `new Employee()` and use the same casing as the classes:

```
var response = new Employee() // Instantiates Employee to ensure correct properties used.
{
    Id = 100, // Has PascalCase.
    Department = new DepartmentModel()
    {
        Id = 200, 
        DepartmentName = "Abc",
        Locations = Employee.Department.Locations
                            .Select(lo => new Location
                                       {
                                             Area = lo.Area,
                                             StreetNo = lo.StreetNo,
                                             Nearby = lo.Nearby
                                        }
                                    ).ToList()
    }
};
```